# regular function defined on $V(F)$ without using closed map of morphisms on projective varieties.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field and let $F\in k[x,y]$ be an irreducible polynomial.

I want to prove that if $z$ is a function regular on all the points of $X=V(F)$ then $z$ is constant. I know that this result is much general thant this particular case, and it's still true for any irreducible projective variety. I know that the general case it's just an application of the closed map for morphism defined on projective varieties (I read this proof on Shafarevich).

I'm trying to complete Fulton Algebraic Curves exercises and I don't want to do the problem using the tools that I mentioned, only the contents of Fulton.

This is my idea: Let $z$ be a regular function on $X=V(F)$ the function $z$ is locally a quotient of polynomials $z=H/G$, note that each $G$ has a commmon solution with $F$ (Bezout Theorem), therefore any representation of $z$ is not global. For each $P \in V(F)$ there exist $H_p,G_p$  polynomials such that $G_p(p) \ne 0$. Let $\mathcal a$ be the ideal generated by the polynomials $G_p$ (the denominators) this is finitely generated, therefore there exist finitely many $G_i$ such that $\mathcal a = (G_1 ... G_n)$. If we show that there exist a common solution $P \in V(F,G_1,...,G_n)$ then we are done because $z$ cannot be defined at $P$. I want to know if I can use Bezout Theorem in the case of finite polynomials or there is another way to prove the result.

Extra: $V(F)$ is the set of zeros of the polynomial $F$ it's also denoted by $Z(F)$

Comment: Can you precise what $V(F)$ is?

Comment: I think you are making mistakes. It is not true that such functions are constant. You are confusing the issue with projective varieties where such results hold. In your special case, take $F=x$. Then $y$ is a non-constant regular function on $V(F)$.